# How to extract files from tree using CMD

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, tree

Let's say I have the following Tree:

```
├───animals
│   │   hippopotamus.txt
│   │   lion.txt
│   │
│   └───dog
│           poodle.txt
│           terrier.txt
│
└───food
    ├───fruit
    │       apple.txt
    │       orange.txt
    │
    └───vegetables
            borcolli.txt
            carrot.txt
            corn.txt
```

What command would I use to create a directory that contains all of the .txt files, but without the subfolders, essentially 'flattening' the tree.

Comment: What operating system? What "command line" are you using? What have you tried so far? The tag "command line" denotes a way of working and on its own is not enough to tell us what you are using.

Comment: @Mokubai CMD, as in the title, refers to windows CMD.exe.

Comment: That's not clear enough. Next time, please add a corresponding OS tag.

Comment: @slhck >Command Prompt, also known as cmd.exe or cmd (after its executable file name), is the command-line interpreter on Windows . 

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe

Comment: @tuskiomi Tags enable users to quickly find questions in which they are interested. Adding an OS-specific tag improves the visibility of your question to those answering and future users asking your same question. Thanks for contributing to Super User.

Comment: @tuskiomi There is a `cmd.exe` tag especially for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

Assuming you have a target directory in mind (C:\Target) and all of the .txt files are under the C:\Tree directory, the following command would get a list of all of the .txt files and copy them to your desired destination:

```
for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b "C:\Tree\*.txt" ') do (copy "%a" "C:\Target")
```

I put double-quotes around parameters that may contain spaces.

## Explanation

```
for /F
```

Performs a for loop parsing text.  By default, tokens will be split on spaces into variables %a, %b, %c, etc.  Since we do not want this behavior, I specified:

```
"delims="
```

Which means no delimiters.  %a will be the variable containing each line of text from the output of our command.  The command I used was:

```
dir /s /b "C:\Tree\*.txt"
```

This performs a directory listing of all files matching *.txt under the C:\Tree folder.  The /s flag performs recursively, searching inside of all subdirectories/subfolders.  The /b flag outputs the listing in a "bare" format, which basically just lists the file and path.  The output looks like:

```
C:\Tree\animals\hippopotamus.txt
C:\Tree\animals\lion.txt
C:\Tree\animals\dog\poodle.txt
C:\Tree\animals\dog\terrier.txt
C:\Tree\food\fruit\apple.txt
C:\Tree\food\fruit\orange.txt
C:\Tree\food\vegetables\borcolli.txt
C:\Tree\food\vegetables\carrot.txt
C:\Tree\food\vegetables\corn.txt
```

And of course:

```
copy "%a" "C:\Target"
```

Copies file signified by the %a variable to the C:\Target directory.  The for loop basically executes the following commands:

```
copy "C:\Tree\animals\hippopotamus.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\animals\lion.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\animals\dog\poodle.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\animals\dog\terrier.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\food\fruit\apple.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\food\fruit\orange.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\food\vegetables\borcolli.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\food\vegetables\carrot.txt" "C:\Target"
copy "C:\Tree\food\vegetables\corn.txt" "C:\Target"
```

For more help on DIR options or FOR loops in Windows Command Prompt (CMD), you can type `help dir` or `help for`.  Beware, the FOR loop help page is quite lengthy.  ;)

Comment: Please let me know if this doesn't quite answer your question.  If it does, please consider accepting this as an answer.  :)

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. Just throwing it out there though, this is one of those things I like doing in PowerShell because it just feels "cleaner"... example: get-childitem -recurse -include *.txt | copy-item -destination C:\Target

Answer (score 1):

A PowerShell solution:

```
mkdir C:\AllTxt ; gci C:\Install *.txt -Recurse | copy-item -Destination C:\AllTxt -Force
```

- `mkdir`creates a new directory, like `C:\AllTxt`
- `gci` gets all txt-Files in `C:\install` (the top directory of your tree structure) recursively
- `copy-item` will copy the files to the destination